# The front of my stove top gets very hot when the oven is on. This is an electric range with smooth glass top

Tags: appliances, range, glass-top-range

The front of my stove top gets very hot when the oven is on. This is an electric range with smooth glass top.
I saw a similar question about a range with coil burners

Is there a quick solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Bad oven door seal.**

The seal around the inside of the oven door keeps hot air in the oven.  Seals can wear out. If the seal is bad, hot hair leaks out of the oven and heats up the front of the range.  Dials can get too hot to touch.

Working on an oven yourself can be a little sketchy but replacing the seal on the interior of the oven door is not such a big deal.  If you do a bad job, the worst thing that can happen is hot air leaks out of the door and you are used to that.

Before you try to replace it, maybe you can just clean it.  I got burned thru my oven mitt yesterday and I felt betrayed.  Mitt!  After all this time??  All this time not washing the mitt, and it was pretty solid with dry stuff in some places.  I washed it and it is fluffy again.  We will see if I get burned.  The same principle applies.  You can clean your oven door seal.  Here is a video though my oven does not look like this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjzDaAl5YOI

I should clean my oven door strip.

If you replace the strip - do I need to say you need to replace the seal with a purpose built oven seal strip?  Because other stuff might melt or cause a fire?   Like that stuff you have in the garage you were thinking about using because you have it, and you are cheap?    There, I said it.   I too am cheap and I think that way.  But replace the door seal strip with a seal made for your oven.